# Wcf data service $expand issue

Tags: wcf-data-services

i am having 2 tables Content and Channel. content having the navigation property of channel

i have created a method "GetContentsOfChannel" in data service which takes channelID as para and return all the contents of that channelID

by executing below uri i am getting all the contents of that channel id

http://localhost:28553/WNADataService.svc/GetContentsOfChannel?channelID=37

but i also want the channel details for each content when i tried with $expand i am getting error

http://localhost:28553/WNADataService.svc/GetContentsOfChannel?channelID=37$expand=Channels

is i am missing some thing or there is any other way by which i can get all the details

please help me

Answer (score 1):

it should be `http://localhost:28553/WNADataService.svc/GetContentsOfChannel?channelID=37&$exp‌​and=Channels`

& in order to add new param to query string
$expand - OData param name to load related entity

Answer (score 0):

Try using ***&*** insteadof ***$***

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you meant to say add & in front of $expand.

Comment: `http://localhost:28553/WNADataService.svc/GetContentsOfChannel?channelID=37&expand=Channels`